# How can a node.js app be deployed to azure via appveyor (pulled from github)?

Tags: node.js, azure, github, deployment, appveyor

I currently have a .net and an angular app, both deployed to azure via appveyor. Now I want to add a node.js app, also in a github repo, also to be deployed via appveyor and into azure.

However I have no idea where to start.

1. What kind of azure app should I create? Just the standard web app service?
2. How do I deploy this to azure via appveyor?

Answer (score 0):

> What kind of azure app should I create? Just the standard web app
>   service?

At first, I could share Azure App Service plan and when we selected one of them with you. Please refer to this document(https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/azure-web-sites-web-hosting-plans-in-depth-overview/ ). Then, for selecting which one service plan, it depended on the site load and requirements. It is not relation to deployment channel.

> How do I deploy this to azure via appveyor?

You can try to follow this guide [Deploying using Web Deploy](https://www.appveyor.com/docs/deployment/web-deploy#azure-web-sites), mark **Package Web Applications for Web Deploy** check box in the **settings**=>**build** tab of your project in appveyor.

Then login Azure Management Portal and download publish profile.Specify the following deployment settings in AppVeyor:

- Server: `https://<publishUrl>/msdeploy.axd?site=<msdeploySite>`
- Website name: `<msdeploySite>`
- Username: `<userName>`
- Password: `<userPWD>`
- NTLM: `disabled`

Replace `<publishUrl>, <msdeploySite>, <userName> and <userPWD>` with values from downloaded publishing profile XML file, in the **deployment** tab.